# C# Message.CreateMessage() Android/Java Equivalent

Tags: c#, java, android, wcf, soap

I am currently trying to figure out a way to have an Android application consume WCF SOAP services. I have access to the server code, but I can't change it and can't post it. (I'm working alongside an existing project as an intern) I have used K-SOAP2 libraries to communicate with public SOAP services, including the NOAA service, so I wouldn't say I'm completely new to the idea.

I've just spent hours studying the layout of the services and see that they are being passed a System.ServiceModels.Channels.Message through CreateMessage(version, string, parameter[], xmlobjectserializer) and I'm wondering how to duplicate this Message object on android.

The xmlobjectserializer is the main thing I'm stuck on. I'm not sure exactly what it is or how I would go about writing one in android.

On top of all that, I'm struggling to find any documentation of how CreateMessage() packages these items up or information on the architecture of a Message (System.ServiceModels.Channels.Message)

Any help would be appreciated and I can elaborate on this if additional information is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If am not mistaken I think that you would want to look at HTTPRequest Class
let me know if this link helps

also Look into using Mono For Android you can create Mono as well using C# 
[Mono Development for Android using C#](http://xamarin.com/monoforandroid)

[HTTPRequest Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.aspx)

Comment: After a fair amount of searching, it looks like the libraries in MonoDroid are going to help me get where I need to be so I'm going to accept this as the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Awesome.. I appreciate that glad I could assist.. have a wonderful rest of the day